# How to create a Segment of just pages that are in a particular Content Grouping?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to view Landing Pages for visits that included viewing pages in a group of pages (a Content Grouping).

So I want to see a list of Landing Pages and the number of sessions that started from each, where the Session included a  visit to a page in the Content Grouping.

That way I can see how many visits to a Content Grouping page were generated by each landing page.

**What I tried**

I think the way to do that is to view Landing Page but use the Content Drilldown's Filter feature (see below).   But I can't see how to do that. The only option I see is Filter :  Content Group   *contains* (or *is* or *matches*, etc.)  some value.

[image]

But I don't know what you'd use for that value to check against. (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: It looks like content groupings have names.   [The documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en) gives the example of "Shirts, Pants, Accessories".  Have you tried entering the names of your content groups each on its own line?